# Speeding up stringdist in R using Parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

I have a vector of 300 sentences, and I am trying to find elementwise JW distance using the `stringdist` package. The execution time for the naive implementation is too high, leading me to look for ways to reduce the runtime. I am trying to leverage the `doParallel` and `foreach` packages, but I'm not getting any significant speedup. This is how I am going about it.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl = makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

sentence = # vector containing sentences 
jw_dist = foreach(i = 1:length(sentence)) %dopar% {
 temp = sentence[sentence!=sentence[i]]
 return(mean(1 - stringdist::stringdist(sentence[i],temp,method = "jw",nthread = 3))
  }
  stopCluster(cl)
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point out ways in which I can speed up this chunk of code.

Comment: So you want to calculate the pairwise distance between the single sentences? In your code you're using parallelism two times, first with `dopar` and then within the `stringdist` function where you specify the number of threads ... I don't think that's good practice

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have observed that the only speedup I get is when I use the `nthread` parameter inside the `stringdist` function. I tried running the code with the `nthread` parameter set to default and `dopar` and did not get any speedup.

Comment: What's your reference time and machine setup? Also, I'm assuming correctly that you want to calculate the distance for each pair of sentences?

Comment: I am planning to run this code with ~1000 sentences, for which this code runs in about 40 seconds. I want to bring it down in the neighborhood of 20 seconds.

Comment: I'm running R version 3.2.2 on a 64 bit machine Running Ubuntu 17.04. And yes, I am looking to calculate the distance for each pair of sentences,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you're fighting with extreme overhead.

Instead of parallelizing on the single sentences, just split the task in some sizable chunks and let `apply` do the rest. I've chosen 10 chunks of 100 sentences each, possibly there's a faster combination but this one works much faster (at least for me) than what you asked for:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

# generate fake sentences

txt <- readLines(url('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&sentences=300&start-with-lorem=1&format=text'))

sentences <- strsplit(txt,'\\.\\s')[[1]]

sentences <- rep(sentences[sample(1:100,100)],10)

# pairwise combinations of sentences
cbn <- combn(1:length(sentences),2)

# simple timing
st <- Sys.time()

# Since you work on LINUX, you can use FORK
cl <-  makeCluster(detectCores(),type = 'FORK')
registerDoParallel(cl)


res <- foreach(ii = seq(1,1000,100),.combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  
  apply(cbn[,ii:(ii+99)],2,function(x) stringdist(sentences[x[1]],sentences[x[2]],method = "jw"))
   
}

stopCluster(cl)
Sys.time() - st
```

On my Ubuntu VM, this code runs in ~ 1.8 seconds.

Specs:

```
Ubuntu 64 bit
R version 3.4
8 CPU cores
32GB RAM Memory
```

HTH

#### Edit:

Maybe avoiding parallel-processing would be a good alternative in this case.

Using this `lapply` version, I can calculate the mean for each sentence in ~ 17 seconds:

```
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:1000,function(ii) c(ii,1-mean(stringdist(sentences[ii],sentences[-ii],method = "jw")))))
```

This will give you a 2 column matrix with the index for each sentence and `1-mean` of all distances to the respective sentence.

Comment: I am looking to calculate the mean JW distance for each entry in `sentence` with every other entry. As such, I will try storing all the pairwise distances from your method in a matrix or something and then calculate a row-wise mean.  Thank you for the tip.

Comment: I was thinking you need the pairwise comparisons. Considering the averages, I updated my solution with a `lapply` version that performs reasonably well.

Comment: Using the method in the update, I can now work with 1000 sentences in just about 30 seconds. I think this is a good start. Thank you for your help !